# Why does @GetMapping method return request param while sending response?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, pojo, getmethod

I get request params as POJO and do nothing in method but in jsp shows parameter which I get from request.Why does method return my object?
Additionally, when I use primitive type or String, It doesn't return object and works perfectly

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/ULD_details")
public String ULD_detailGet(ActionError ID){
return "ULD_detail";
```

JSP

```
 <tr>
    <td >ULD id</td>
    <td>${actionError.ID}</td>   
</tr>
```

Link

```
http://localhost:8080/UCM-controller/ULD_details?ID=1145
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't return your object. It returns the String "ULD_detail", which is the name of the view to execute.

This view is executed, and finds an `actionError` bean in the request attributes (i.e. in the model), because the [Spring documentation about handler methods arguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments) says:

> Any other argument
>
> If a method argument is not matched to any of the above, by default it is resolved as an @RequestParam if it is a simple type, as determined by BeanUtils#isSimpleProperty, or as an @ModelAttribute otherwise.

And the [documentation of ModelAttribute](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html#name--) says:

> The default model attribute name is inferred from the declared attribute type (i.e. the method parameter type or method return type), based on the non-qualified class name: e.g. "orderAddress" for class "mypackage.OrderAddress"

Comment: Thanks, as far as i understand, there is no need to return param which is resolved as @ModelAttribute, to view (JSP). It always exists in request attributes. Is It true?

Comment: You keep using the term `return` for something other than wat `return` means. But indeed, the whole point of ModelAttribute is to expose the argument in the model.

Comment: If I get param as ModelAttribute from jsp and do something in controller method there is no need to set that param to request in order to show it in jsp in response.  yes? Does that param  live during request as well as response?

Comment: A model attribute ends up being stored in a Http servlet request attribute. The request, just as the response, exists for the whole duration of the request handling, including in the JSP handling this request and generating the response body. The code in your question shows that.

Comment: Thanks for explanation